# Creating sub branch structures and pushing

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-checkout

I want a similar structure to the below graph.

Say I clone a project from github which has a `main` branch.

I then want to create a `server` branch at the time which the `main` branch had its **2nd commit**.

Would I create a branch off of my local branch `main` which clone the github `main` branch?

So would it look something like this?

```
git checkout -b main_local server
```

Then how would I update my main_local branch with server branch and then push the changes to reflect in the github main branch?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a branch on a previous commit (**2nd** commit of your `main`-branch), need this command:

```
# in main-branch
git checkout -b server <sha-of-2nd-commit>
```

To become the changes from `server` branch to your `main` branch, execute following command:

```
# change to main branch, when in server-branch
git checkout main

# merge server branch to main
git merge server
```

**Attention:**
This can give *merge conflicts*, if you have in both branches change the same file at the same place (line).

After merging, type following to push the changes from *local* `main`-branch to *remote* `main`-branch:

```
# in main-branch
git push
```

Comment: Very nice, for the first command i should be in the main local branch?

Comment: Yes in the `main` branch

Comment: Hey i wanna aska  question, say for example if i clone a project from Github on two different computers. If i create different branches on these computers will they show up for each other?

Comment: Simple answer: NO. For more, read this [git-branch tutotial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches). But for other questions please ask a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).